# Running a form handled by ajax in a loaded ajax page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Using tutorials found i'm currently loading new pages with this:

```
$("a.nav-link").click(function (e) {
        // cancel the default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the address of the link
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        // getting the desired element for working with it later
        var $wrap = $('#userright');
        $wrap
            // removing old data
            .html('')
            // slide it up
            .hide()
            // load the remote page
            .load(href + ' #userright', function () {
                // now slide it down
                $wrap.fadeIn();
            });
    });
```

This loads the selected pages perfectly, however the pages have forms that themselves use ajax to send the following:

```
  var frm = $('#profileform');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
```

However this is not sending the form as it did before the page itself was called to the parent page via ajax. Am I missing something? Can you not use an ajax call in a page already called by ajax?

I also have other issues, for example I disable the submit button unless there are any changes to the form, using:

```
    var button = $('#profile-submit');
var orig = [];

$.fn.getType = function () {
    return this[0].tagName == "INPUT" ? $(this[0]).attr("type").toLowerCase() : this[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
}

$("#profileform :input").each(function () {
    var type = $(this).getType();
    var tmp = {
        'type': type,
        'value': $(this).val()
    };
    if (type == 'radio') {
        tmp.checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    }
    orig[$(this).attr('id')] = tmp;
});

$('#profileform').bind('change keyup', function () {

var disable = true;
$("#profileform :input").each(function () {
    var type = $(this).getType();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if (type == 'text' || type == 'select') {
        disable = (orig[id].value == $(this).val());
    } else if (type == 'radio') {
        disable = (orig[id].checked == $(this).is(':checked'));
    }

    if (!disable) {
        return false; // break out of loop
    }
});

button.prop('disabled', disable);});
```

However this also doesn't work when pulled to the parent page. Any help much appreciated! I'm really new to ajax so please point out any obvious mistakes! Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Just an update to what i've found. I've got one form working by using:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#profile', function() {
```

However the following:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#cancelimage', function() {   
$('#cancelimage').onclick=function() {
function closePreview() {
    ias.cancelSelection();
    ias.update();
    popup('popUpDiv');
    $('#imgForm')[0].reset();
} }; });
```

Is not working. I understand now that I need to make it realise code was there, so I wrapped all of my code in a mouseover for the new div, but certain parts still don't work, so I gave a mouseover to the cancel button on my image form, but when clicked it doesn't do any of the things it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across it, if you've got a function name assigned to it, it should pass fine regardless. I was trying to update it, and there was no need. Doh!

```
function closePreview() {
        ias.cancelSelection();
        ias.update();
        popup('popUpDiv');
        $('#imgForm')[0].reset();
     };
```

Works just fine.